# Adding to ArrayList from EditText

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to implement a button that saves integers entered into an `EditText` and save them into an `ArrayList`. I declared my ArrayList globally in my class and am calling it inside of my `OnClickListener` method. I am unsure whether or not I am saving to this `ArrayList` because I am unable to display what I have saved in said `ArrayList`.

My declaration of the list is;

`ArrayList<String> savedScores = new ArrayList<String >();`

This is what I am using to save to my `ArrayList`;

```
`savedScores.add(input1.getText().toString());`
```

Now, in my `OnClickListener` method, I have a button that saves user input into the `ArrayList` (or so I am hoping), and another to display what I have saved. However, when I click on the "editScore" button, the `TextEdit` is cleared as if I have nothing saved in my `ArrayList`. This is simply a test to see if I am properly saving to my array and any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

```
switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttTotal:
                if (blankCheck.equals("")) {
                    Toast blankError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU CANT SKIP HOLES JERK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    blankError.show();
                    break;
                } else {
                    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString()); //Get input from text box
                    int sum = num1 + score2;
                    score2 = sum;
                    output1.setText("Your score is : " + Integer.toString(sum));
                    input1.setText(""); //Clear input text box

                    //SAVE TO THE ARRAYLIST HERE
                    savedScores.add(input1.getText().toString());
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.allScores: //CHANGE THIS TO AN EDIT BUTTON, ADD A HOLE NUMBER COUNTER AT TOP OF SCREEN!!!!!
                output1.setText("you messed up");
                break;
            case R.id.editScore: //Need to set up Save Array before we can edit
                output1.setText(savedScores.get(0));
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are saving empty values into your `ArrayList`. See here

```
 input1.setText(""); //Clear input text box

 //SAVE TO THE ARRAYLIST HERE
 savedScores.add(input1.getText().toString());
```

The value of `input1` is empty. Clear the input after you saved it to the array.